# Display indicator value without plotting anything

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to modify a pine script indicator on TradingView so that it displays the value of the indicator/plot next to the title of the indicator on the main chart. However, I don't want to actually plot anything because it messes up the scale of the chart. I also don't want it to show up in a separate window above or below the chart. Is this possible with Pine Script?

[image]

I attempted passing in display=display.none to the "plot" function, but that removed both the value label and the line. Here is the code (image example does not have "display" parameter):

```
//@version=4

study(title="ADR %", overlay=true)
length = input(20, title="length")

dhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
dlow  = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

adr = 100 * (sma(dhigh/dlow, length) - 1)

plot(adr, title="ADR %", display=display.none)
```

Answer (score 8):

Using plot with tranp=100 will work but it can mess up the chart scale. I usually use the plot character function to accomplish this because you can set the location to top or bottom so it doesn't impact the scale. Just set the character to "" so it doesn't put anything on the chart.  Something like this:

plotchar(adr, title="ADR %", char="", location=location.top)

Comment: How to do opposite: Keep line and hide related number only (not all numbers)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting the transparency to 100% in the pine script code and then changing the settings of the chart to only scale the price chart.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
display = display.data_window + display.status_line
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want...
Note: it only works with Pine Script version 5 because my understanding is that version 4 does not allow you to detect the background color.

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="ADR %", overlay=true, precision=1)
length = input.int(20, title="length")

dhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
dlow  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

adr = 100 * (ta.sma(dhigh/dlow, length) - 1)

plotchar(adr, title="ADR %", char="", location=location.bottom, color = color.white)
plotchar(close, title="ADR %", char="", location=location.bottom, color = chart.bg_color)
```

Change the color (of the first line of code that plots) to whatever you want. I noticed you're using a dark background and so I picked white. The 2nd line of code that plots effectively hides the indicator on the chart; the indicator is still on the bottom but you'll never see it because it's set to the background color.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix the axis to scale on price only.

Right click on the axis then enable "Scale Price Chart Only"

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
plot(someValue, title = "Some Value", display = display.data_window,  editable = false)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**