# Print the pourcentage of each candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Is it possible to print on the top or buttom of each candle the value like the % ? Like this one (just the %)

[image]

Comment: Never used PineScript, but I guess this might be a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756058/display-indicator-value-without-plotting-anything Good luck!

Comment: Thnaks for the link but not this ;)

Comment: @chprot. Please post the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the price change in percentage then use the `label.new()` function to create your labels.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

per = ((close-close[1]) / close[1]) * 100
per_s = str.format("{0,number,#.##}", per)

label.new(bar_index, high, per_s)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your help.  I have absolutly not this thinking process.